# Indexes on a database table, one column common

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am trying to understand if it makes sense to have two separate indexes in the following scenario:

```
ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
```

I have queries

```
1.  where ColumnA = xxx and columnB = xxx
2.  where ColumnA = xxx and ColumnC = xxx
```

If I create only one index, that is on `ColumnA`, will that help in both queries? Or shall I create two indexes Index1 on `ColumnA` + `ColumnB` and Index2 on `ColumnA` + `ColumnC`.

I understand having two index will provably better but I am trying to keep the number of indexes low because the table is rather big but `columnA` is fairly unique. `ColumnA` filters data of a particular entity and that entity can delve into that data only always.

Also, if there an index on `ColumnA` + `ColumnB` and if a query comes in which `ColumnB` is first and ColumnA second, will this index be used?

Comment: "*If I create only one index, that is on ColumnA, will that help in both queries?"* I think you mean to ask whether you should make one index on ColumnB? The queries have ColumnB in common, not ColumnA.

Comment: Sorry, I think I mistyped.  ColumnA is common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, creating an index on `ColumnA` only should help both queries. Indexes in most RDBMS things (MSSQL, MySQL, etc.) are b-tree structures. The key allows for fast looking down the line, in one direction only.

Additionally, creating a *deeper* index such as `ColumnA, ColumnC` should also help both queries, since the `ColumnA` component is still indexed first.

I would suggest evaluating which column is selected most frequently: `ColumnB` or `ColumnC` and applying an index to it with `ColumnA`.

An example: let's say that `ColumnB` is accessed in only 10% of the `ColumnA` queries whereas `ColumnC` is accessed 90%. In this case I'd set the index on `ColumnA, ColumnC`. It will help 100% of the A-C queries, and will probably (I'm not 100% certain in MySQL) help the A-B query as well since the system is generally smart enough (at least in MSSQL) to use the A-C index to select the `ColumnA` data in the A-B query (but still doing a full scan for the `ColumnB` component).

These kinds of indexes by the way are called *covering indexes* because your query selects only the columns included in the index data (which is a slight optimization as well).

The best read-performance will be 2 indexes (one for each set), however as you correctly noted this will slow down inserts, updates, and deletes a little. Not enough that you're likely to notice in most cases though.

Answer (score 2):

(@Haney discusses the Question from one point of view; here is another.)

2 indexes is not 'bad'; 10 indexes is getting into a gray area of "too many indexes".

`INDEX(A)` *helps* with both of your queries.

`INDEX(A,B)` is very good for one of your queries, while *helping* with the other query.  If you wanted to keep it to a single index, this might be the best choice.

But... if `B` is a `TEXT` column, you won't be allowed to use `INDEX(A,B)` because of size limitations.  And, using a "prefix" `INDEX(A, B(22))`, though possible, may not be any better than `INDEX(A)`.

Don't bother with `INDEX(A,B,C)`.  This is good for the query with A and B, but it is not any better than `INDEX(A)` for the other query.